# How can i loop html element using jquery in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to repeat 'post' div and all of its contents eg 50times in left-col div using jquery and call it inside html?

HTML:

```
 <div class="post"> Content </div>
```

JS:

```
var jQueryScript = document.createElement('script');
jQueryScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js');
document.head.appendChild(jQueryScript);

$(document).ready(function(i) {
for (let i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
  $(".post:eq(0)").clone().appendTo(".left-col");
}


 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(i) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    $(".post:eq(0)").clone().appendTo("#left-col");
  }
});
```

There was a few problems with your code. First `$("#post")` should be `$(".post")`, since it's a class not an id.

Second your `for` loop was not correct. You were missing the `{}` and also it should be `i < 50` not `i < i.length(50)`

Also important to note that I've added `:eq(0)` to `$(".post")`, since it would cause a big problem without.
Because first time the loop would run, you would have 1 element with the class `post`, second time you would have 3 elements, third time = 6 elements and so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function(i) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    $(".post:eq(0)").clone().appendTo("#left-col");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post"> Content </div>


<div id="left-col"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, changed it( left-col was also an id) ,how should i call this function in html now? Or it should append it right away to left-col?

Comment: Since you have added `document ready` then you can call it basically where ever you want. since it will not run until the page is ready.

Comment: If you have your javascript in its own file, you're good, as long as you make sure it is included. Else include the js code in HTML with a ```<script>``` tag.